How important is "research-fit" in post-doc hiring
To clarify, this is my definition of "research-fit": research-fit is a term used in academia to describe the (degree of) overlap between research interests—and presumably also experience—of two or more individuals. It is commonly used in PhD admissions to match applicants to potential advisors.
I am wondering whether a similar analysis is done during post-doc hiring decisions. Of course, if an English PhD applied to a physics post-doc, the answer is somewhat trivial. However, consider the following hypothetical scenario:
A theoretical computer scientist decides that they want to study algebraic geometry and indeed, they have trained in algebraic geometry (perhaps through demonstrable coursework), but have published only in theoretical computer science with possibly a small overlap that an algebraic geometer might not care all that much about. Would, then, an absence of "research-fit", in particular the absence of relevant research experience in algebraic geometry, be a hurdle in said computer scientist's interest to pursue a post-doctoral position in mathematics despite adequate training? I am not thinking of computational algebra, but rather, pure mathematics.
More broadly, are there situations where faculty may be interested in (or even have need for) post-doctoral candidates from outside their field?

I think a lot hinges on "despite adequate training". Is coursework in the area without research experience considered "adequate training" by the hiring advisor, or not? It seems like you have decided you have "adequate training", but if a potential advisor does not hire you, their reason for not hiring could very well be that they do not think your training is adequate for the position.

Clearly the people hiring you have to see some fit for what you would do for them and what they could do for you.

(Not a full answer but still): in the UK, shortlisted applicants are usually first divided into "employable" (for the position), and not. I suspect that the hurdle you may face is that you could be found "employable" in many of your applicants, but if somebody with a better "research fit" applies, you may not be the top ranked amongst those candidates that got a "pass" and therefore not get offered the position

You might have picked bad examples as areas of research, but... well less than half of algebraic geometry PhDs obtain a postdoc position - despite having finished a dissertation that likely requires learning substantial background material beyond what is taught in a yearlong algebraic geometry course - it's possible that the theoretical CS PhD does have ideas and insight that are of interest to the algebraic geometers doing the hiring, enough to overcome most likely having less background than all the competition that is already not getting a postdoc, but I'm not sure how likely.

@AlexanderWoo: I know comments are not for extended discussion, but I have to ask -- where do the other half end up?

@principles-investigator: They either end up in teaching-oriented academic jobs, either temporary or permanent, or they end up in an industry job, almost always unrelated to algebraic geometry, frequently in some sort of software development.  (Thankfully, most of these temporary teaching-oriented jobs are at least full-time.)  Outside of the top 20 or so departments, PhD graduates who land a research-oriented position are rare.

This depends entirely on the group one is joining. I've seen a situation where there were no expectations at all, other than the general subfield of math. But there are other situations where a post doc is hired for a specific purpose and the PI (say) is looking for an expert in that precise topic.
The first case I mentioned was more to see if a promising faculty candidate would fit into a department (he did, and was later hired as an assistant professor). But the short term of most post doc positions might indicate that some specific talent is needed in a specific project.
And, anything in between is also possible. Each position is distinct. Read the announcement for hints and ask people doing the hiring about "fit".
Most post docs, however, are expected to produce something. I think it rare that it is treated as a purely educational opportunity.

It depends on the job, the hiring panel, and the competition. I was once on a committee looking to hire a physical oceanographic modeller. It was difficult to find good candidates in that field at the time, so as well as interviewing a couple of physical oceanographers, we interviewed an applied mathematician with a strong programming background and a physical limnologist. In the end, we hired the mathematician. More recently, I was on a hiring committee looking for a marine ecologist with a particular skill set. We interviewed — and seriously considered — a terrestrial ecologist who had an impressive CV and had the skills we were looking for, but in the end, we took the safer bet of hiring someone who was already working in marine ecology. The stronger your CV, the more likely you are to be considered for a job outside your immediate research area. The harder it is to find good candidates in the field you are aiming for, the more likely it is that you will get a look-in. But if there is strong competition from people who have been working in exactly that area, you’re a long-shot.

Depends on where the money is coming from and what the demands are. Typically agencies or sponsors with strict timelines and deliverables necessitate a tighter overlap because we don't have time to get people up to speed.
Industrial money has strict deliverables, often with weekly meetings. The postdoc better be directly aligned and start producing ASAP. DoD/NASA with monthly meetings, there can be a bit of flexibility. DoE with quarterly, even more so. NSF doesn't really fund postdocs so no comment there. NIH (still trying to crack that nut). Foundation/fellowship money is the best because the postdoc is free to explore and learn, and typically just a short report is required annually. I just hired one of the latter and it was more fun looking for people who could bring a diversity of background to some of the projects I have going, without any strict pressure to produce right away. Whereas my current search for an industrially-funded postdoc is a bit of a headache as I need some very specific skills, and I need their start dates to align.

In theoretical mathematics in the US, most postdocs are hired on university money through a combination of the teaching budget and endowed funds.  They are in effect temporary junior faculty members.  Also, they are hired by the department as a whole, not individual faculty (though some departments effectively delegate the choice to individual faculty members or groups, possibly on a rotating basis).

@AlexanderWoo -- that is going to vary by institution.  At my R1 institution, we are the opposite.  All postdocs (regardless of field) must be guaranteed by the appointing PI; no teaching or dept funds available at all.  We don't let them hire anyone without a guarantee of funding (from a portfolio manager).  If it later happens that the PI cannot afford them, they are let go (with necessary notice, etc.).

@AlexanderWoo, in relation to R1NaNo's answer: what kind of timeline do these post-docs hired by the department work with? Are they on similarly tight schedules as industry funded ones, or more relaxed timelines or perhaps somewhere in between? Additionally, I assume there are some teaching expectations as well?

@principles-investigator -- when you do contract work (not grant work) you may only have a couple weeks' notice before the start date of the contract.  If you tend to make offers to postdocs in the spring for a fall start date, but your contract starts in July, what do you do?  Wait until next fall to get a postdoc?  The contract could be over by then or you are so far behind it causes problems with your sponsor.

Thanks @yourfriendlyresearchadmin, that makes sense; but perhaps I should clarify that I meant more in the way of workload and deadlines for deliverables.

@principles-investigator - departmental post-docs in the US are usually hired on approximately the same timeline as faculty, though maybe slightly later - applications due November-January with offers January-March for jobs starting in August-September, and jobs run with the academic year (since teaching is involved).

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin - that effectively means you have almost no postdocs in theoretical mathematics (not counting those that come with their own funding) since grants in theoretical mathematics are less common (a majority of R1 faculty do not have one) and very few such grants include money for a postdoc (because one can't expect even a highly qualified unknown person to be able to contribute to a specific project as their ability to generate insight might not combine with that particular project).

@AlexanderWoo, sorry; I actually merged theory CS and applied math in my head. Yes probably for theory math less common to have grant funding, but that's because regular research grants are less common, not because of NSF as a sponsor disallows postdocs as this answer indicated.  For theory CS and applied math, our people use NSF funding all the time.  NSF allows postdocs on regular research grants.  Even if we budget a grad student, we are allowed to rebudget into postdoc as part of normal rebudgetary rules. If theory math people can get an NSF grant, it can pay for a postdoc.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin: NSF is skeptical about postdoc and grad student funding in theoretical math - yes it can happen (particularly on CAREER grants since they are required to be quite large (for theoretical math)) - and of course it happens on grants from programs that require a training component - but few regular grants include personnel funding beyond a month of summer salary for the PI.

Research administrator here -- I work at an R1 and support PIs with various fields, but specifically Computer Science.  I help with the appointment process for portfolios assigned to me, so I would like to mention some possible administrative hurdles based on my experience with a diverse group of people within the same institutional policies.  Overall, I want to emphasize that there is a widening gap in the culture of hiring in CS from the rest of the engineering and applied sciences.  Because of the competition with Big Tech, there are more options for postdocs, and they know them and use them to their advantage.  Sometimes that is ok, but often I find many more obstacles with the appointment process because we are competing with industry to make competitive offers.  I have not found there to be equal pressure in the other departments.
Need for Specific Expertise
As an example, we have cases where a materials engineer requires a computational person on their project, and they find it more useful to add such a person to their group rather than create a collaboration with someone else in another group/institution.  Here are some questions I would raise for this scenario:

Are you paying this person the same as the rest of your lab?  In this case, CS people make much more than materials postdocs.  This can cause issues in the lab.
Is this person being appointed with the title of postdoc in CS or in Materials?  Are there rules requiring one title over the other (e.g., based on their PhD field)?
What are the specific advantages of personally mentoring someone who does not have the same background as you?  If they are on your grants and you are the PI -- you have to oversee their work.  How will you do this if you do not know their field?  Who will help them if you cannot?
Are there visa issues that prevent this from working out?  There could be a problem for OPT paperwork if that is a factor and a different field is used in the appointment process.

I have seen this work out in cases like this, but the PI needs to be very engaged and work to find solutions for the obstacles that will inevitably arise.  It's not an "easy" path.
Hoping for a Strong Postdoc in the Lab Regardless of 100% Fit
I have seen cases, particularly in CS, more than other fields, where postdocs appear to be looking for a temporary home and use the PI as a stepping stone.  The PI also is hoping to get some help in the lab, and due to a shortage of postdocs, accept the individual.  I never saw this happen ten years ago; it's now much more common, and something I am wary of.  Once they are in the lab, I have seen postdocs actually refuse to work on their PI's grants and projects.  As you can imagine, this is pretty upsetting for the PI.  They felt like they had a strong person in their lab, but it turns out this individual was not interested in the PI's topic, and thus, it caused tension in the group.  My questions in these cases:

How do we pay a person who doesn't want to work on the PI's projects?
How can the PI mentor someone where their research interests do not align?
Does the PI need to be able to go through a disciplinary process and are they prepared to do this if necessary?

In these cases, the postdoc often ends up leaving on bad terms.  I do not advise this situation at all.
General Advice
Overall, you need to make sure offer letters are clear on what the topics will be that need to be worked on.  Make sure that this will help if you need to go through a disciplinary procedure.  Talk to your faculty affairs/appointing office prior to making offers.  If the difference in field is large, ask about salary requirements.  Check on visa requirements if that is a factor.  Try to find additional support on the intellectual side so that you are not alone in mentoring this person.
Make sure you know about all of the possible hurdles with making an appointment and keeping the relationship stable before entering into a complicated appointment.
